# How to check if variable contains "Insert" or "Update" in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have SQL query in variable like "Select * From Customers"

I would like to check if variable contains "Insert" or "Update".
Next activity would be executed only if variable do not contain "Insert" or "Update".

How to do it?

Comment: Can you please give more information on what you are looking for? How your variable contains Insert/update when your variable holds SQL query? Can you please provide a snippet if possible?

Comment: Use an IF activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if(contains(variables('query'),'insert'),'true',
if(contains(variables('query'),'update'),'true','false'))
```

Use such an expression in if activity as Koen mentioned.

when the expression evaluates to false, it means, there is neither insert nor update in your variable